# File, strip each line and add to key in dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary

How do we split the first line in a text file and make them as keys, and
every line after that are the values for each key. *Without any imports*

What I have so far:

```
new_dict = {}
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        list = line.strip().split(',')
        for item in list:
            new_dict[item] = []
```

what this outputs: `{'name': [], 'last': [], 'middle': []}`

Now, how do I move on to the next line, split at the comma and append the first element to the first key, the second element to the second key, etc.

```
file:
name, last, middle
bob, jones, m
jones, bob, k
alice, lol, f
```

Result in the end:

```
{'name': ['bob', 'jones', 'alice'], 'last': ['jones', 'bob', 'lol'], 'middle': ['m', 'k', 'f']}
```

Comment: They did say "without any imports."

Comment: Why "without any imports"? I thought in python you just "import solution"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_dict = {}
names = [] # used map 0, 1, 2 to `name`, `last`, `middle`
with open('/path/to/test.txt') as f:

    # Handle header (the first) line: `name, last, middle`
    for name in next(f).split(','): # split fields by `,`
        name = name.strip()  # remove surrounding spaces
        names.append(name)
        new_dict[name] = []  # initialize dictionary with empty list.

    # Handle body.
    for line in f:
        # enumerate(['bob', 'jones', 'm']) return an interator
        #    that generates (0, 'bob'), (1, 'jones'), (2, 'm')
        for i, value in enumerate(line.split(',')):
            new_dict[names[i]].append(value.strip())

print(new_dict)
```

output:

```
{'middle': ['m', 'k', 'f'], 'last': ['jones', 'bob', 'lol'], 'name': ['bob', 'jones', 'alice']}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but could you explain to me this part:     for name in next(f).split(','):
        name = name.strip()
        names.append(name)
        new_dict[name] = []

Comment: @Sc4r, I added comments to the code. Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: What does next(f) do? Is it the next line after the first?

Comment: @Sc4r, `next(f)` return a line; used to get the first line. It's like `f.readline()`

Comment: Oh ok now that make sense, I wasn't to sure what next did. Could you also explain the enumerate part as well please?

Comment: @Sc4r, `enumerate(x)` generates .. `(0, x[0])`, `(1, x[1])`, `2, (x[2])`, ....    See [`enumerate` from Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = {}
for attr in "name last middle".split():
  answer[attr] = []
with open("path/to/input") as infile:
  for line in infile:
    for k,v in zip("name last middle".split(), line.strip().split(',')):
      answer[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess the logic is:

1. Read the first line, split it on `,`.
2. Take each value and create the keys of a dictionary.
3. Read the rest of the lines and add them to a list corresponding to the correct 'column' or key.

Here is an approach for the above logic:

```
d = {}
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   first_line = next(f)
   for column_title in first_line.split(','):
       d[column_title.strip()] = []
   for line in f:
       if line.strip():
           # this will skip blanks
           name, last, middle = line.split(',')
           d['name'].append(name.strip())
           d['last'].append(last.strip())
           d['middle'].append(middle.strip())
```